# How do I un-highlight a previously selected line in an MFC CListCtrl programmatically (VS 6)?

Tags: list, mfc, clistctrl

Does anyone know how to un-highlight a previously selected line in an MFC CListCtrl programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To de-select the 20th item:

```
YourListCtrl.SetItemState(20, 0, LVIS_SELECTED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't work if the the List view is Report style ie multiple columns. Do you have any solution for that?

One can set the List property as:

```
m_ctlList.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

which always selects the particular line when user clicks on that line, but if programmer deletes a line in the list view, the next row replaces the selected one and the row is un-highlighted.